# Delete a worksheet based on conditional statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a macro in an excel file, which is used to manipulate a different file.  After opening the file, I want to scroll through each worksheet and delete a sheet if is named "For Export"  The following clip worked at one point, not sure what changed. I now get an "Object required" error on the worksheets delete line.

```
For Each S In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
MsgBox (S.Name)
    If S.Name = "For Export" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbook.Worksheets(S.Name).Delete
    End If
Next S
```

Comment: **THIS**Workbook.Worksheets(S.Name).Delete or more simply S.delete (and add Exit For before End If).

Comment: Neither of these methods did anything,  I think they were referring to the file where tthe macro is stored, not the second file.

Comment: You started the loop using `For Each S In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` so yes, you are looking in the workbook where the code is written. Maybe change to ActiveWorkbook or properly define the workbook you want to work on.

Comment: Down Vote, because "ThisWorkbook" will not loop through the worksheets in the "different file". "ThisWorkbook" implies the workbook with the vba code.

Answer (score 1):

If you change "Workbook.Worksheets(S.Name).Delete" to "S.Delete" it should delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
For Each S In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    MsgBox (S.Name)
    If S.Name = "For Export" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        S.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = true
        exit for
    End If
Next S
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked, thanks.

```
For Each S In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If S.Name = "For Export" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    S.Delete
    End If
Next S
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your breaking line to:
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(S.Name).Delete